# Инициализация FragmentAdapter и Fragment

Tags: android-fragment

В приложении есть 3 табы, в качестве тестирования (в плане изучения) в каждый из них добавил свой фрагмент (FavouritesFragment, StoriesFragment, VideoFragment), который наследуется от Fragment. В конечном итоге в моих фрагментах отображается список переделенных объектов, который я получаю и добавляю через метод setData (TabsFragmentAdapter) в  onPostExecute в процессе выполнение AsyncTask в Main.

Табы я проставляю через свой фрагмент адаптер

```
public class TabsFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private Map<Integer, AbstractFragment> tabs;
private Context context;

private List<NewsDTO> data;

private StoriesFragment storiesFragment;
private VideoFragment videoFragment;
private FavouritesFragment favouritesFragment;


public TabsFragmentAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, List<NewsDTO> data) {
    super(fm);
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
    initTabsMap();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabs.get(position).getTitle();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return tabs.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabs.size();
}

private void initTabsMap() {
    tabs = new HashMap<>();
    storiesFragment = StoriesFragment.getInstance(context, data);
    videoFragment = VideoFragment.getInstance(context, data);
    favouritesFragment = FavouritesFragment.getInstance(context, data);

    tabs.put(0, storiesFragment);
    tabs.put(1, favouritesFragment);
    tabs.put(2, videoFragment);
}

public void setData(List<NewsDTO> data) {
    this.data = data;
    storiesFragment.refreshData(data);
    favouritesFragment.refreshData(data);
    videoFragment.refreshData(data);
}
}
```

Вот пример класса фрагмента, остальные аналогичные.

```
public class VideoFragment extends AbstractFragment {
private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_video;
private List<NewsDTO> data;
private NewsListAdapter newsListAdapter;

public static VideoFragment getInstance(Context context, List<NewsDTO> data) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    VideoFragment fragment = new VideoFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    fragment.setContext(context);
    fragment.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.video));
    fragment.setData(data);

    return fragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);

    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycleViewVideo);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    newsListAdapter = new NewsListAdapter(data);
    rv.setAdapter(newsListAdapter);


    return view;
}

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void setData(List<NewsDTO> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public void refreshData(List<NewsDTO> data){
    newsListAdapter.setData(data);
    newsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}

public class AbstractFragment extends Fragment {
protected Context context;
protected View view;
private String title;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
}
```

При попытке запустить приложение вылетает null pointer, путем дебага выяснил что не инициализируется newsListAdapter, тоесть не вызываеься метод onCreateView.
При чем проблема не в фрагментах, если я в фрагмент адаптере меняю местами добавление фрагментов в Map, то проблема возникает именно с последним добавленным фрагментом.

Полный код можно посмотреть [тут](https://github.com/Despedo/Rss-Msrcedes/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/despedo/rss_msrcedes)

Подскажите, где ошибка и почему возникает проблема с последним фрагментом.

Comment: Немного смущает "@Nullable" перед OnCreateView, что, если его убрать?

Comment: Эти аннотации добавляются автоматически, и означают что метод может принимать nul в качестве входных параметров. Я конечно попробую ради интереса его убрать, но сомневаюсь что это исправить ситуацию.

Comment: Имею в виду над "@Override", получается, метод может возвращать null, а не из-за этого ли exception

Comment: Попробовал убрать "@Nullable", как и предпологал результата это не дало, может кто-то еще что-то подскажет?

Answer (score 0):

Опять же путем дебага нашел в чем проблема :). И так, оказывается при выполнении MainActivity инициализируются только фрагменты в первой и второй табе, третий же инициализируется только если перейти на третий или второй таб (соседний).

Не знаю почему так, может кто объяснить.

Вот и получается что я пытаюсь проставить данный в NewsListAdapter который еще не проинициализирован, так как фрагмент не начал свой жизненный цикл.
Надо теперь думать как переделать архитектуру приложения с учетом вышесказанного, но это уже другой вопрос...